# Poisson distribution CDF

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

Let the arriving cars are distributed with Poisson distribution with mean 1. We are supposed to find cdf  for time W of the arrival car if we are said that at he end of the second hour only one car arrived. 
I am not familiar with gamma functions, so I tried to differentiate the pdf, but I literally have no idea how to imply this information on one car arrived during 2 hours.

Thanks

Comment: We have a poisson distribution with mean $1$ and are you asked to find the CDF for time $W$ where the car arrived during $2$ hours? I am not sure I understand your question. Where is this question coming from?

Comment: @Wolfy this is my inter-college study book for our midterm exam preparation, I am confused as well as you. I believe we are supposed to find not "universal" cdf expression, but with regard to 1 car in first two hours and only then combine it with general cdf form from 2 hours to some T.

Comment: If exactly one car arrived in two hours in a Poisson process, then the likelihood of its arrival time and none after that time will have been uniform across those two hours